# SQLite substr function in WHERE expression

Tags: sql, sqlite, substring, substr

Suppose I have 'employee' table with 'lname' column

I am interested in fetching all rows, where second character can be either 'e' or 'o'

What i am doing wrong, this query doesnt return anything:

```
SELECT * FROM employee WHERE (substr(lname,2,3)='e' OR substr(lname,2,3)='o');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the third parameter in [substr](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html) is the length, not the end character

change to `substr(lname,2,1)`